# Insert column at very end with blank cells in between

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue with inserting a column after my last column. I am using the below code, but I have blanks all throughout my data so it is inserting a column about halfway through. It is confusing because row 1 is completely full all the way until the end so I figured that would trump the blank cells throughout, but it is still inserting a column halfway through.

```js
function AddColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");
  sheet2.insertColumnAfter(sheet2.getLastColumn());
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you share an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best way but

```
function AddColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");
  sheet2.insertColumnAfter(sheet2.getDataRange().getValues()[0].length);
}
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly given that I will always want it at the end of the data table I have. Thank you!